# lattepanda with fedora server 25 can't use mysqld command

Tags: mysql, fedora

already installed mysql-server package but it doesn't work

Package mariadb-server-3:10.1.21-3.fc25.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.

Dependencies resolved.

Nothing to do.

Complete!

[root@localhost ~]# /etc/rc

rc0.d/ rc1.d/ rc2.d/ rc3.d/ rc4.d/ rc5.d/ rc6.d/ rc.d/

[root@localhost ~]# /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld start

-bash: /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Fedora is using systemd so you should use `systemctl` for starting services:

```
systemctl start mysqld
```